# VSCode terminal is not opening in Linux (POP_OS 20.10)

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: can't open the zsh (default terminal)]

[image: Can't open bash terminal also]

> Any solution to fix this problem
> VSCode details

```
Version: 1.55.2
Commit: 3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
Date: 2021-04-13T09:37:02.931Z
Electron: 11.3.0
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.11.0-7614-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true
```

change it from false to true in VSCode settings